# Errors trying to publish npm package

Tags: npm-publish

I published fine last week but I tried today and it does not work on any of my computers.  It is weird, at first I thought there was an issue with the service but then I started doing some solutions I found on the web and now I get this when I try `npm adduser`:

```
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - PUT https://npm.pkg.github.com/estebanpadilla/-/user/org.couchdb.user:ludusy
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404  'org.couchdb.user:ludusy' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 Your package name is not valid, because 
npm ERR! 404  1. name can only contain URL-friendly characters
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/estebanpadilla/.npm/_logs/2020-08-11T03_27_17_364Z-debug.log
```

I looked all over for a possible solution but nothing seems to work.

`npm whoami` gives this result:

```
npm ERR! code ENEEDAUTH
npm ERR! need auth This command requires you to be logged in.
npm ERR! need auth You need to authorize this machine using `npm adduser`

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/estebanpadilla/.npm/_logs/2020-08-11T03_29_57_501Z-debug.log
```

Does anyone have an idea on how to get it working again?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're not logged in. I think you need to run `npm adduser` and follow the prompts.

Just a quick tip -- make sure to carefully read the error message. I think this line is telling you exactly what you need to do! `npm ERR! need auth You need to authorize this machine using npm adduser`.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your reply. I did but I still get the error after writing the username, the password and the email.

Comment: also `--verbose` parameter could help to get some details

Answer (score 0):

It is working now, for some reason I was not able to run npm adduser or npm whoami on the project directory but I was able on any other directory so I figure there was something wrong with some configuration file inside the project. I removed any file that wasn't essential and it work.

Thanks for your help.